# MULE 4 - Secure Properties config issue changing the algorithm

Tags: security, mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I did all the encryption process setting a secureKey but I chose Blowfish algorithm, but now I need to use AES as the algorithm but I changed the config in the secure property config (in my global) it seems that is not recognizing the algorithm change, and if I want to encrypt I still need to choose Blowfish and the same secureKey, to desencrypy or encrypt

Do you know why?
or what can I do to modify the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

If you encrypt information with an encryption algorithm you **must** use the same algorithm to decrypt it. You can not use a different algorithm. That's how encryption work.

Encrypt again the properties with AES this time and then use also AES in the secure properties configuration.

Comment: Yes, what I meant, is that now, I decrypted everything, and then I changed the algorithm to AES but is still encrypting with Blowfish is not recognizing the AES change

Comment: How did you encrypted the properties exactly? Please share the command used.

Comment: please provide more details